# Degree of smooth maps between $S^n$ and $\mathbb{RP}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

To give some context these two exercises come from a past exam of my undergraduate course in differential geometry, course which followed loosely Milnor's "Topology from the differentiable viewpoint". I have no knowledge about the theory of Homology/Cohomology and only basic notions in algebraic topology. The exercises are the following.

Prove or give a counterexample for the following statements:

$i$) all smooth maps $h:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^2$ have $\deg_2(h)=0$ ($\deg_2$ being the degree mod $2$).

$ii$) There exist a smooth map $r:S^3\rightarrow\mathbb{RP}^3$ such that $\deg(r)=6$

There are two facts which I thought could be useful here, the first being that $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is homeomorphic to $ {S^n}/{v\sim -v} $ , while the second one is that we can construct smooth maps of arbitrary degrees between $S^n$ and itself, I'm not aware of a standard construction of this but it seemed reasonable to me that we could construct a smooth vector field on $v:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $k$ non degenerate zeroes $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ contained in $B_1(0)$ such that $\det{Jv}_{x_j}\gt 0$ and then consider the map $\widehat{v}=\frac{v}{||v||}$ restricted on the set ${\partial B_1(0)}\sim S^n$. This would give us a smooth map from $S^n$ to itself with degree $k$. Equivalently, we can require the opposite sign for the determinant of the Jacobian of $v$ if we wish to obtain a $-k$ degree smooth map.

With this in mind, for the second point, if we constructed a smooth map $R:S^3\rightarrow S^3$ such that $\deg{R}=3$ we could then consider $q:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^3$ given by $q(x)=\left[x\right]$ the equivalence class of $x$, then $\deg{(q\circ R)}=\deg{R}\cdot\deg{q}=3\cdot2=6$, of course this argument requires $q$ to be smooth.

What can we say about point $\left(i\right)$? Are there flaws in my reasoning regarding point $\left(ii\right)$?

Comment: Your argument for (ii) is fine, although the smoothness of $q$ is irrelevant (it is smooth though). Regarding (i), note that $S^2$ is simply connected while $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is not. What does that tell you about any map $S^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for the feedback. Isn't the smoothness of $q$ necessary for $r=q\circ R$ to be smooth?

Comment: As for point ($i$), we know that since the two fundamental groups are distinct we cannot have an homeomorphism between the two spaces, however to conclude we would require some stronger condition, for example that no continuous and surjective function between the two exists, this however I'm not sure is the case

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise the map $r$ was required to be smooth, my bad. As for (i), are you familiar with the lifting property of covering maps?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese unfortunately not, could you suggest some reference?

Comment: Section 1.3 of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), in particular, Proposition 1.33.